# VSCode Extension API showInputBox call producing unexpected behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

According to the VSCode extension docs, the [InputBoxOption](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InputBoxOptions) `ignoreFocusOut` is described thusly:

```
Set to true to keep the input box open when focus moves to 
another part of the editor or to another window. 
This setting is ignored on iPad and is always false.
```

I am not using an iPad, so I can presumably ignore the second sentence.

When I do set this property to true, I see absolutely no behavior change. That is,
as soon as I click in some other window the VSCode input box closes. Am I misinterpreting what this property is supposed to do? Or is this behavior broken?
My typical use looks like this:

```
    state.url = await input.showInputBox({
      ignoreFocusOut: true,
      title: this.title,
      step: 1,
      totalSteps: this.maxSteps,
      value: state.url ?? '',
      prompt: 'Enter remote Git URL',
      validate: this.validateProtocol,
      shouldResume: shouldResume,
    });
```

If there is, in fact, no way to alter that undesirable behavior of the input closing (and thus the command terminating),
is there perhaps a way to resume the command? That is, I have a multi-step dialog of 5 steps. Upon restoring focus to the VSCode window can I continue with, say, step 3, where I left off? I have not seen any indication this is possible but thought I would ask while I am here.

(My system: VSCode/macOS version 1.74.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a more targeted site to post the same question and got an answer there:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/407